# Is there an open source autonomous vehicle simulator with control over traffic?

Tags: motion-planning, navigation, simulation, autonomous-car, webots

As a part of my research work I'm supposed to build or use an existing autonomous vehicle simulator, in which I can also control the behaviour of the traffic in the system, I was searching on Google and posted on reddit to check if there is any such simulator (open source), After all the exhaustive attempts, I haven't found anything yet.

I'm trying to build this in V-rep or any other ROS compatible simulators. The end product has to look something like the one shown here, [YouTube - Webots: The autonomous vehicle simulator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhzZ6Ao6Shc), and would also give control over the traffic behaviour. Any help/suggestion is greatly appreciated.

PS: I do know that there's this one written in Unity, [Github:A self-driving car simulator built with Unity](https://github.com/udacity/self-driving-car-sim) ([An Open Source Self-Driving Car](http://udacity.com/self-driving-car)), but we are looking to import OSM data and also Unity doesn't have a good ROS integration mechanism.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Josyula Krishna, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site, and that includes shopping for software. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Comment: Thank you Mark, If Google and Reddit also do not have a proper answer to this question, then i guess this is something worth asking for, i have been searching for 2 weeks and still wasting my time, i'd love to hear atleast an opinion on the subject from the people who are experienced in the area. As i'm pretty new to this field i want to save myself from anything that might go wrong.

Comment: It sounds like what you are after may not be available outside of private research labs. Your best option might be to take the existing open source project and enhance it with the functionality you need. Best of luck, and sorry that this isn't a good place to answer your question. If you have more specific questions, feel free to ask them here, we may be able to help with implementing your ideas later.

Comment: Try searching instead for traffic simulators--drop the autonomous vehicles aspect. SUMO is an open-source microscopic traffic simulator, which can probably do whatever you need as far as traffic is concerned.

Comment: Thanks NBCKLY I know of SUMO, i'm actually thinking of wrapper for V-Rep if its possible.

Comment: FYI Webots (the simulator in the movie you posted) has been released open-source since December 2018. You could use its famous SUMO wrapper for free: https://github.com/omichel/webots

Comment: Thank you Fabien, and yes i'm using it these days.